# ¿Como usar variables PHP con MYSQL query WHEN?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

El problema que tengo es que quiero actualizar una tabla con los datos "fecha" y "precio" siempre y cuando la fecha de mi variable php sea diferente a la ultima fecha que existe en la tabla "Producto".
Les dejo el código que estoy intentando hacer que funcione.

```
$Fecha_1 = 2020-05-02
$Precio_1 = 1500

    $sql = "INSERT INTO Producto (Fecha, Precio)
VALUES ('$Fecha_1', '$Precio_1')
CASE
WHEN (SELECT Fecha FROM Producto ORDER BY Fecha ASC LIMIT 1) != $Fecha_1
ELSE 
END";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
```

No puedo hacer funcionar el codigo, nose si estoy implementando mal el WHEN o las variable php dentro de la query.

Mi objetivo es que la query detecte que ya hay un dato("Precio") con determinada "fecha" y no vuelva a cargar un "precio" con una fecha ya existente.

---

No puedo hacer funcionar el codigo, nose si estoy implementando mal el WHEN o las variable php dentro de la query.

Mi objetivo es que la query detecte que ya hay un dato("Precio") con determinada "fecha" y no vuelva a cargar un "precio" con una fecha ya existente.
Nose si me explico. Gracias por contestar.

Comment: Cual es el problema que presenta?

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
INSERT INTO Producto (Fecha, Precio)
VALUES (
    SELECT '$Fecha_1', '$Precio_1'
    FROM dual
    WHERE (SELECT Fecha FROM Producto ORDER BY Fecha ASC LIMIT 1) != '$Fecha_1'
)
```

Tienes una demo [aquí](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ebbf6f/1).

De todas formas, parece que lo que intentas es no hacer un insert si existe un registro  con la misma fecha.

Creo que mirarlo de esta manera es complicarlo. Además, no tienes garantías de que alguien inserte el mismo valor entre que se resuelve la subquery e insertas el registro.

La manera correcta de hacerlo es haciendo que la columna Fecha sea única (de forma que deba dar un error si alguien intenta insertar un duplicado de fecha)

Esto lo puedes hacer definiendo una [Primary Key](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clave_primaria) para tu tabla (si es que no la tenía)

Si la tabla ya tenía una primary en otra/s columna/s, lo que puedes hacer es definir un índice UNIQUE:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX FechaUnica ON Productos (
    Fecha ASC
);
```

De esta manera, si intentas insertar un registro con una fecha duplicada no te dejará, te devolverá un error. Luego, en tu código php puedes comprobar este error y si se trata de un error de registro duplicado, simplemente lo ignoras o lo tratas con la lógica que desees.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Estoy aprendiendo y sabia que podria estar encarando mal el problema. Un saludo y gracias por tu tiempo. Voy a intentar solucionarlo